# Doesn't work radio transmission from Arduino Uno to Arduino Pro Micro

Tags: arduino-uno, networking

I have Arduino Uno, Arduino Pro Micro, XY-MK-5V and FS1000A.
I need transmit data from Pro Micro to Uno.

Transmitter:

```
    #include <VirtualWire.h>

    void setup() {

      Serial.begin(9600);

      vw_setup(2000);
      vw_set_tx_pin(14);
    }

    void loop() {

      send("Test message!");  
      delay(2000);
    }

    void send (char *message)
    {
      vw_send((uint8_t *)message, strlen(message));
      vw_wait_tx();
    }
```

Receiver:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    vw_set_rx_pin(12);
    vw_setup(2000);

    vw_rx_start();
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;

    if(vw_get_message(buf, &buflen))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < buflen; i++)
        {
            Serial.print(buf[i]);
        }

        Serial.println();
    }
}
```

I dont know why it's doesn't works. When I changed Uno with Micro and Micro with Uno, it's worked.

But I need: Micro + transmitter FS1000A & Uno + receiver XY-MK-5V.

Please help me. I'm using [this Pro Micro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpDfX.jpg).

Comment: What in particular *doesn't work*? You don't receive any characters? You get a garbage message?

Comment: And which Pro Micro: the geniune SparkFun Pro Micro - which version (it says on the PCB); the A-Star variant; a cheap chinese copy?

Comment: Are you connecting the modules to the right pins? `vw_set_tx_pin(14);` looks a bit odd, if you used that on the UNO.

Comment: On a Pro Mirco, `D14` is connected to the RX LED, and nothing else; it's not broken out to either of the headers so you would never be able to use it to connect to an external component.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers. I solved this problem, my Chinese copy has problems with power.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @NickGammon The problem was solved according to feok. This is an answer although it has not been accepted.